# Case expression issue with Null's

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, case

I am training on a northwind database but got stuck in a case statement, i am placing the query below and would appreciate assistance.

The issue is i want the records in column Shippeddate to have some text in this case i placed 'ddd' when there is NULL on it, but NULL's keep appearing in the result set.

```
SELECT OrderID, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate, 103)    AS OrderDate, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RequiredDate, 103) AS RequiredDate, 
       CASE ShippedDate 
         WHEN NULL THEN 'ddd' 
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ShippedDate, 103) 
       END                                     AS ShippedDate 
       -- Why is this not working 
       , 
       [UnitPrice]                             AS UnitPriceOnOrder, 
       [Quantity]                              AS QuantityOnOrder, 
       [Discount]                              AS DiscountOnOrder, 
       CompanyName_II                          AS CustomerCompanyName, 
       ContactName_II                          AS CustomerContact, 
       ContactTitle_II                         AS CustomerContactTitle, 
       City_II                                 AS CustomerCity, 
       Country_II                              AS CustomerCountry, 
       ProductName, 
       CategoryName, 
       [Description]                           AS CategoryDescription, 
       UnitsInStock, 
       UnitsOnOrder, 
       UnitsInStock - UnitsOnOrder             AS AvailableUnitsInStock, 
       FirstName + ' ' + LastName              AS EmployeeName 
FROM   ##NorthwindTestI 
WHERE  [Quantity] > 10 
       AND ShippedDate > '19970101' 
        OR [UnitPrice] > 10 
        OR Country_II = 'USA' 
        OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName = 'Janet Leverling' 
ORDER  BY 
--[Quantity] 
ShippedDate
```

Comment: thanks for edit Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WHEN ShippedDate IS NULL` instead of `CASE ShippedDate WHEN NULL`:

```
SELECT .....,
       CASE WHEN ShippedDate IS NULL  
        THEN 'ddd' 
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ShippedDate, 103) 
       END  AS ShippedDate 
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `ISNULL()` instead:

so rather than

```
CASE ShippedDate 
         WHEN NULL THEN 'ddd' 
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ShippedDate, 103) 
       END                                     AS ShippedDate
```

use:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ShippedDate,103),'ddd')
```

so your query will be like:

```
SELECT OrderID, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate, 103)    AS OrderDate, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RequiredDate, 103) AS RequiredDate, 
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ShippedDate,103),'ddd') AS ShippedDate 
       -- Why is this not working 
       , 
       [UnitPrice]                             AS UnitPriceOnOrder, 
       [Quantity]                              AS QuantityOnOrder, 
       [Discount]                              AS DiscountOnOrder, 
       CompanyName_II                          AS CustomerCompanyName, 
       ContactName_II                          AS CustomerContact, 
       ContactTitle_II                         AS CustomerContactTitle, 
       City_II                                 AS CustomerCity, 
       Country_II                              AS CustomerCountry, 
       ProductName, 
       CategoryName, 
       [Description]                           AS CategoryDescription, 
       UnitsInStock, 
       UnitsOnOrder, 
       UnitsInStock - UnitsOnOrder             AS AvailableUnitsInStock, 
       FirstName + ' ' + LastName              AS EmployeeName 
FROM   ##NorthwindTestI 
WHERE  [Quantity] > 10 
       AND ShippedDate > '19970101' 
        OR [UnitPrice] > 10 
        OR Country_II = 'USA' 
        OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName = 'Janet Leverling' 
ORDER  BY 
--[Quantity] 
ShippedDate
```

Comment: Thanks guys that was quick, both solutions worked, brilliant.